# I can't send SMS on indian numbers from my Twilio account

Tags: java, api, twilio, sms-gateway

I am registered from UK in Twilio. I am using Java library for sending SMS. When i trying to send message on Indian number giving me error message like

```
{
  "code": 21612,
  "message": "The 'To' phone number: +91_____________, is not currently reachable using the 'From' phone number: +44____________ via SMS.",
  "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21612",
  "status": 400
}
```

I also read instruction of given in link https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21612. I also verified that number provided is a properly formatted in E.164 and Twilio also provide service for this number carrier.

I want to implement global SMS gateway.
What is solution for this problem ??

Comment: Hi Rajesh, there are some limitations on sending SMS to Indian mobile devices at the moment. Please see https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices for more information.

Comment: Hello @philnash, you are right but this problem is not occurred behalf of this.If any Indian number is enabled DND (Do Not Disturb) mode then this problem will occur which is mentioned in https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be addressed to Twilio support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i ask to Twilio support team they replied me that You are getting this error as UK Long numbers cannot send international sms, however numbers such as American number can do. When i tried "American number" in the "from" field i was able to sent messages to indian number.

But here is also DND(Do Not Disturb) mode problem is arise for indian numbers. DND (Do Not Disturb) enabled numbers not receive message.

Answer (score 3):

can you try making sure that you have allowed geographic access to India in your Twilio account? Log into the portal, click on the drop down next to the date, choose account, then select geographic permissions, finally make sure that India has check marks allowing access to that area.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello Louis Lewis, there is geographic access to india also enabled ..

Comment: Hi Rajesh, best I can think of, is for you to perhaps contact me and get the to number to me, I will then quickly write a test app of my own and see if I can send an sms to the same number. Perhaps via chat?